# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: It doesn't give a error number

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

This is the error:
    A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number:

select a.FOLIO, a.direccion, b.DESC_COLONIA, C.DESC_MPIO 
from emergencias@db1 a INNER JOIN AMSGEOCODING@db1 Z ON A.FOLIO=Z.FOLIO inner join cat_colonia@db1 b on A.CVE_COL=b.cve_col and A.CVE_MPIO=b.cve_mpio and A.CVE_ent=b.cve_ent INNER JOIN CAT_MPIO@db1 C ON C.CVE_MPIO =A.CVE_MPIO AND C.CVE_ENT=A.CVE_ENT WHERE a.folio>=8782583 and z.LATITUD =0 and z.LONGITUD<>-1

Filename: C:\wamp\www\myapp\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

What could be wrong with this?

this is my C:\wamp\www\myapp\application\config\database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost/orcl',
    'username' => 'local',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'orcl',
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: seriously, without an error message there's no way we can diagnose this.

Comment: Db not connected try `'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',`

Comment: the problem was in the query, when I add tis line "INNER JOIN AMSGEOCODING@se066sureste Z ON A.FOLIO=Z.FOLIO "

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that table, I still don't know what is the problem